# SP Online : add publishing image field to custom new form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form

I added a publishing image field to a list and it shows up fine in newform.aspx, but not in a custom new form (which is where I need it). It DOES show in the data sources in SP Designer but I can't get it into the form.